# Rendered texture looks different from material and render viewport - Why?

Tags: rendering, cycles-render-engine, texturing

I can't understand why the texture renders with very low detail (even though the other textures stay the same after render). What could it be?
[image]

[image]

Comment: *Everything* looks blurred out, not just what you've circled.  Render/preview disagrees in a ton of ways.  Things we'd want to know: rendering engine; render dimensions and settings; camera file of view-- tons more.  Your material nodes, shown, are not impacting this, but there are a lot of other variables that could be.  Consider providing a file for us to just see everything.

Comment: So the bluriness is just because in the rendered image, I zoomed-in considerably to match preview. I'm working in cycles and the camera settings match the settings of the 3D camera track and the live action camera. Here is a stripped down file with the packed texture. https://mega.nz/file/2fgXAADS#6g_vv4Dj-e4Bqlrf_X2NSkKGnCXK9tfghQCs0tQlhPY (I uploaded to mega as it is over 24mb)

Comment: I redownloaded file.  Again, I'm not seeing an appreciable difference between rendered preview and render.  Looks like my other renders.

Comment: Thank you for checking it out. I appreaciate it a lot!